# Select element by its content and remove the first and last character of its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-apps-script, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic page which fetches data from Google App Script and makes a visualization with them.

This is the code which I use as `HTMLService`

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName);

    function drawSheetName() {
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('/*query contents*/');
        query.send(drawTable);
    }

    function drawTable(response) {
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height:'100%'});
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
```

So, I want to select the values of the last column of the visualization and remove the first and last character of them with `CSS, JS, JQuery`...no matter.

The values always contain `<a href` so the selector can be defined via contents of the element or its row number. I will try to explain with code what I'm trying to do but it is incorrect, because I am mixing the languages.

```
<script>
    var select = $( "td:contains('<a href')" );
    select.slice(1, -1);
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
    document.getElementByTagName("TD"):contains('<a href').slice(1, -1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop each row to remove the first and last character of the last column. Replace the `drawTable` function with the below

```
function drawTable(response) {
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height:'100%'});
        $(".google-visualization-table-table tr td:nth-child(11)").each(function() { // Assuming 11 is the last column number
           var data = $(this).text();
           $(this).text(data.slice(1, data.length - 1));
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('some_selector')` returns an object, so you cannot use slice on an object, it should be a string, like this after you get your `td`s :

`var toBeSliced = "Hello world"; // string
    toBeSliced = toBeSliced.slice(1,toBeSliced.length -1 ); // cut off first and last chars
    console.log(toBeSliced);`

after you get your html tags using which contain data you can use `element.textContent.slice( _ , _ ) ;`

[String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: so you may do the following :
1. get you html elements which contain your targeted data.    
2. iterate over the result of your query.    
3. get the text ( string ) content of each element you get.    
4. do slicing